# How to restore packages from Artifactory using YAML

Tags: azure-devops, artifactory

The guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core?WT.mc_id=azurepipelines-blog-dabrady&view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) gives the example code below:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: NuGet.config    # Relative to root of the repository
    externalFeedCredentials: <Name of the NuGet service connection>
```

but I'm struggling to know what is required in place of `<Name of the NuGet service connection>` or even `NuGet.config`.

The Guide on [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Azure+DevOps+and+TFS+Artifactory+Extension) doesn't use YAML or even mention it so I don't know if it is even possible.

My question: Is the above possible, and if so, what should I have in the script above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Name of the NuGet service connection>` is exactly what it says. Go create a [service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops) in your project that points to the NuGet feed, then reference it by name there.

Comment: Easy when you know how... I’m new to azure devops so didn’t realise the guide was referring to a service connection in azure or that these even existed. Thanks.

Comment: @Percy Again, it's telling you the problem. You created the wrong feed type. It's expecting an External NuGet feed service connection, not an Artifactory service connection. If you installed some sort of Artifactory extension in the marketplace, there may be Artifactory-specific build steps you can use.

Comment: Perfect answer. You can find service connections in your project's settings under Pipelines > Service Connections. You will want the service connection type to be 'NuGet' (not 'Artifactory').