# DOTNET Restore Failing because feed thinks the PAT is a an encrypted Api Key

Tags: azure, api, encryption, key, restore

When I try to run the below step in Azure DevOps I am seeing an error on the restoration of the first package. When I remove the First Credential it restores from the second feed without issue, so it seems like the issue is with the first feed.

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '$(Parameters.RestoreBuildProjects)'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: nuget.config
    externalFeedCredentials: 'FirstCredential, SecondCredential'

ERROR
Using authentication information for the following URI: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxxxxxxxxx/_packaging/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/nuget/v3/index.json
##[error]Error: DotNetCore currently does not support using an encrypted Api Key.
##[error]Packages failed to restore
```

Answer (score 0):

I know previously when using the dotnet CLI to publish NuGet packages to an authenticated source I have needed to use the `--store-password-in-clear-text` flag (as worrying as that seems). There is more documentation available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source) .

You could try passing the above flag inside the `arguments` input of your [task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops#arguments) but I can't guarantee it will work.

Failing that, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793508/5209435) it looks like you will need to create a service connection and reference that by it's name in place of providing the username and password in the `externalFeedCredentials` property.